# Implement range function in clojure return error

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I am trying to implement the range function in clojure, but my implementation is returning an error that I cannot understand. Here it is:

```
(defn implement-range [a b] (
  if (= a b)
  (conj nil b)
  ((conj nil a) (implement-range (inc a) b))))
```

I am trying to do in a recursive way, it is not complete yet, since I am stuck with this error:

```
ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  user/implement-range
```

I think that it is a parentheses problem that I cannot see (I am a newbie in clojure :) ). Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for any help

EDIT:

I would like to return something like (1 2 3 4) if I call the function like this:

```
(implement-range 1 5)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `((conj nil a) (implement-range (inc a) b))`?

Comment: I am trying to add elements to a list recursively. But as I was researching I changed this to list, instead of conj

Comment: With `((conj nil a) (implement-range (inc a) b))))`, you're trying to call `(conj nil a)` as a function, with `(implement-range (inc a) b)` as the argument. Is that your intention?

Comment: haha, no. I see now that this does not make sense at all. I will post my partial solution as an answer so you can see if make sense, and possible ways to improve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close:

```
(defn implement-range [a b]
  (if (>= a b)
      '()
      (conj (implement-range (inc a) b) a)))

(implement-range 0 5)
=> (0 1 2 3 4)
```

First, the main problem is that `((conj nil a) (implement-range (inc a) b))))` is attempting to call `(conj nil a)` as a function, with `(implement-range (inc a) b)` as the argument. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do here, but this definitely isn't what you want.

I made three changes:

- You need to `conj` the current number to the *result of the recursive call*. This is "unsafe" recursion since the recursive call isn't in tail position, but while messing around, that's not a big deal. You'll want to use an alternate method though if you intend to use this for real.
- If you enter a `b` that is larger than `a`, it will explode. I fixed this by changing the base case condition.
- Your base case didn't make any sense. Once the recursion stops, you'll want to add to an empty list.

Just a side note, any time you see `((`, little alarm bells should go off. This is *often* a sign of a problem, unless you're getting fancy and writing something like `((comp str inc) 1)`; where the first form in the expression evaluates to a function.

Comment: Thank for your answer, and for the tips. I changed the base return value to nil and after that removed the nil values. It is ugly I know, but as I said I am still a newbie in clojure . Your answer is easier to read than mine :)

Comment: @GabrielMesquita Really, you should be using a good IDE to write with. Clojure is a great language, but it's difficult to write easily unless you have something helping you with braces. I use IntelliJ+Cursive, which is free, and a great IDE. That odd opening brace on the first line of the function definition wouldn't even work using parinfer.

Comment: parinfer lets you write Clojure using indentation, like you were writing Python. It handles your braces for you based on the indentation.

Comment: Awesome, I started to learn clojure 3 days ago haha I am using atom with proto REPL. I will give intellij a try :)

Comment: It's a huge IDE, so it will take some getting used to. I've been using it for 2 years though, and I'd say it's definitely worth the time investment to learn.

Comment: Oh, and read my addition to the bottom. That's an important thing to think about when you're starting out. Early on, you should really never have two opening braces next to each other unless you're really getting fancy.

Comment: I've used intellij working with java, I think it should be similar right? Yes thanks a lot for the tips :)

Comment: The only difference is the Cursive plugin, which adds the typical highlighting and REPL support. It's the same IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I did some research and found that use conj this way does not make any sense. So I came up with this:

```
(defn implement-range [a b] (
  if (= a b)
  b
  (flatten (list a (implement-range (inc a) b)))))
```

So if I call the function with the 1 4 parameters the result will be:

```
(1 2 3 4)
```

But, since I am trying to implement a function such like the range function, it needs to remove the last element yet.

**EDIT 1**

The final function that I wrote looked like this:

```
(defn implement-range [a b] (
  if (= a b)
  nil
  (remove nil? (flatten (list a (implement-range (inc a) b))))))
```

**EDIT 2**
After some more research I've figured out another way to solve this, with less lines of code:

```
(defn new-range [a b]
  (take (- b a) (iterate inc a)))
```

Comment: I would not use flatten.  That is a very roundabout way of building a nested structure, just to un-nest it!  Using `cons` or `conj` is much simpler & more natural.

Comment: Yes the answers above are more readable and idiomatic. This answer works but is far from the ideal way of implementation.

Answer (score 1):

the simplest (and the most classic one) would be something like this:

```
(defn implement-range [a b]
  (when (< a b)
    (cons a (implement-range (inc a) b))))

user> (implement-range 1 20)
;;=> (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19)
```

Comment: Also lazy, when wrapped in a `lazy-seq` before the `when`